JNI libs not found when compile spring boot project on GraalVM for AWS lambda
I downloaded original AL2023 docker image and compiled my project there using command
 mvn -Pnative native:compile -DskipTests
But when I upload it to lambda I get the error:
Failed to load the native runtime interface client library libaws-lambda-jni.linux-x86_64.so. Exception: Specified file not in the JAR: libaws-lambda-jni.linux-x86_64.so
Failed to load the native runtime interface client library libaws-lambda-jni.linux-aarch_64.so. Exception: Specified file not in the JAR: libaws-lambda-jni.linux-aarch_64.so
Failed to load the native runtime interface client library libaws-lambda-jni.linux_musl-x86_64.so. Exception: Specified file not in the JAR: libaws-lambda-jni.linux_musl-x86_64.so
Failed to load the native runtime interface client library libaws-lambda-jni.linux_musl-aarch_64.so. Exception: Specified file not in the JAR: libaws-lambda-jni.linux_musl-aarch_64.so

I use the following maven plugin setup
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build-native</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-native</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
<!--                    <mainClass>myapp.MyApplication</mainClass>-->
                    <mainClass>com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda</mainClass>
                    <imageName>my-worker</imageName>
                    <buildArgs>
                        <buildArg>-H:DynamicProxyConfigurationFiles=src/main/resources/proxies.json</buildArg>
                        <buildArg>-H:-ReduceImplicitExceptionStackTraceInformation</buildArg>
                        <buildArg>-H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces</buildArg>
                        <buildArg>--verbose</buildArg>
                        <buildArg>--enable-url-protocols=http</buildArg>
                        <buildArg>-march=compatibility</buildArg>
                        <buildArg>-H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=src/main/resources/reflect-config.json</buildArg>
                        <buildArg>
                            --initialize-at-build-time=org.springframework.boot.loader.nio.file.NestedFileSystemProvider
                        </buildArg>
                    </buildArgs>


                </configuration>

            </plugin>

Please help me to understanf why this error happens, thanks

Explain your problem statement. I see you trying to use Lambda and Docker in your project. Why

Are you deploying a docker image to Lambda? Or a zip/jar file to Lambda?
